# How do I represent complex subqueries and calculated tables in Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following SQL that basically works. How would I represent this in Django ORM? I'd like to avoid running a full raw query

I am not sure how to go about the subquery in Django ORM and how to properly execute the cartesian product (achieved by the CROSS JOIN)

```sql
SELECT datum,
       alldata.worker_id,
       reporting_plan.project_id,
       SUM(effort::float)/60/60
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT datum,
                   reporting_plan.worker_id AS worker_id
   FROM
     (SELECT datum::date
      FROM generate_series('2019-05-01', '2019-12-31', '1 day'::interval) datum) AS dates
   CROSS JOIN reporting_plan
   ORDER BY datum,
            worker_id) AS alldata
LEFT OUTER JOIN reporting_plan ON alldata.worker_id = reporting_plan.worker_id
AND datum <= reporting_plan.end
AND datum >= reporting_plan.start
GROUP BY datum,
         alldata.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.project_id
ORDER BY datum,
         alldata.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.project_id
```

The expected result is a list with all dates in the timeframe and all workers and matching planning information (projects and effort).

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Based on the feedback from @jimjimjim I managed to remove the CROSS JOIN while getting the same results:

```sql
SELECT datum::date,
       alldata.worker_id,
       reporting_plan.project_id,
       SUM(effort::float)/60/60
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT generate_series ('2019-05-01', '2019-12-31', '1 day'::interval) AS datum,
                   worker_id
   FROM reporting_plan
   ORDER BY datum,
            worker_id) AS alldata
LEFT OUTER JOIN reporting_plan ON alldata.worker_id = reporting_plan.worker_id
AND datum <= reporting_plan.end
AND datum >= reporting_plan.start
GROUP BY datum,
         alldata.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.project_id
ORDER BY datum,
         alldata.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.project_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question here is a bit different from the Reddit one, with this approach you will be making a raw query but returning ORM objects. I will do the following:

1. Create a model for the query:

```
    class WorkerEffort(models.Model):
        date = models.DateField(...)
        worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, db_column="worker_id")
        project = models.ForeignKey(Project, db_column="project_id")
        effort = models.DecimalField()

        class Meta:
            managed = False
```

managed information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#managed

2. Perform a [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) query to that model:

```
WorkerEffort.objects.raw('''
SELECT datum,
       alldata.worker_id,
       reporting_plan.project_id,
       SUM(effort::float)/60/60
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT datum,
                   worker_id
   FROM
     (select *, generate_series(start, end, '1 day'::interval) as datum from reporting_plan) 
     ) AS alldata
LEFT OUTER JOIN reporting_plan ON alldata.worker_id = reporting_plan.worker_id
GROUP BY datum,
         alldata.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.project_id
ORDER BY datum,
         alldata.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.project_id
''')
```

With the raw query, you will be able to match the ids with the ORM objects through the WorkerEffort (Query Model).

Comment: Thanks! This sound to me a little bit like a work around. Is this a "Django-way" of doing things?

Comment: I tried it, and it works. But it is not nice. I like the idea of the unmanaged `WorkerEffort` Model,. I'll try to figure out to build my ORM around that.

Comment: It's not a good "Django-way", but for complex queries sometimes is the only way around. But maybe you could create a view that takes care of "all_data" and the left outer join. And then create a no-managed model for that view, in which you could perform the group by and query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you the same result? It eliminates the cross join, which would make it easier to re-write using the ORM, and since the series is generated using `reporting_plan.start` and `end`, you don't need to include those in the join condition. If the dates given in your query need to be parameterized, you could include them as arguments in an ORM command, rather than the query itself.

```
SELECT datum,
       alldata.worker_id,
       reporting_plan.project_id,
       SUM(effort::float)/60/60
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT datum,
                   worker_id
   FROM
     (select *, generate_series(start, end, '1 day'::interval) as datum from reporting_plan) 
     ) AS alldata
LEFT OUTER JOIN reporting_plan ON alldata.worker_id = reporting_plan.worker_id
GROUP BY datum,
         alldata.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.project_id
ORDER BY datum,
         alldata.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.worker_id,
         reporting_plan.project_id
```

Comment: This gives me an error: `syntax error at or near "end" LINE 9: (select *, generate_series(start, end, '1 day'::interva... ^`     Also, I actually need the time range, as reporting_plan contains plan objects that are outside of the range I want to select

Comment: I managed to remove the CROSS JOIN based on your feedback, see my edit in the questions. Thanks!